# How to get items from a ListViewCtrl multiple selection in WTL?

Tags: visual-c++, listview, wtl

I have a `ListViewCtrl`  in a **WTL** program.

I need to get the items selected by the user(multiple selection).

I can only het the count of selected items using `GetSelectedCount()`.

`GetSelectedItem()` doesnt work with multiple selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here:

```
CListViewCtrl ListView = ...
for(INT nItem = ListView.GetNextItem(-1, LVNI_SELECTED); nItem >= 0; nItem = ListView.GetNextItem(nItem, LVNI_SELECTED))
{
  // Here you go with nItem
}
```

Comment: Yes that did!! I was trying with `ODS_SELECTED` :(

Answer (score 2):

Now this is just the way that I did it:

```
for(int j=0;j<list.GetCount();j++)
{
    if(list.GetSel(j))
    {
        list.GetText(j,strTemp);
        doSomething(strTemp); //maybe put in an array
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the try! But there is no `GetSel()` for `ListViewCtrl` in **WTL**

Answer (score 1):

shortest way:

```
int nItem = -1; 
while ( (nItem = m_lvList.GetNextItem(nItem, LVIS_SELECTED)) != -1 ) 
{ 
...
}
```