# how to pass item (0) of a palylist into a variable of type string

Tags: listview

How do I pass item number 0 from my list called `listview` into a variable of type string called `inputword`.
Here is the part that I need help with:

```
inputWords=   (String) listview.??????;
```

I have tried all the methods that I thought were relevent including `.getitemselected` and `.tostring`.

Comment: Does this deserve a language tag?

Comment: What language is this? Java? Is this an actual `ListView` or a list? Can you post the code where you define `listview`?

Comment: Without any context this question has no meaning, please provide what language, and context for the question.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using c# as i suspect you do use:

```
inputWords= listview.Items[0].Text;
```

if you are using java

```
inputWords = listView.getItemAtPosition(0).toString();
```

on c++ i don't know, but i found this cool [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933477/how-to-get-items-from-a-listviewctrl-multiple-selection-in-wtl) saying:

```
list.GetText(j,strTemp);
```

though i'm not sure what's `strTemp`
that was a productive questiong after all...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language you're using, but I think you would want to use the 'items[].text' property. So in C# you would use:

```
inputWords = listview1.Items[0].Text
```

And if you are using Visual Basic you would use:

```
inputWords = listview1.Items(0).Text
```